# Adding Custom Field to Review Order Step in Magento Checkout

Tags: magento, checkout, custom-fields

I was following the walkthrough here: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page.

I originally asked to open of a question about a custom field not saving to the table when the field was moved to the review order step instead of the billing step as the article referenced. So I am rephrasing my question since I narrowed this down as far as I can. This is my Observer class

```
class Excellence_Custom_Model_Observer{
public function saveQuoteBefore($evt){
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    $post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
    if(isset($post['custom']['sales_person'])){
        $var = $post['custom']['sales_person'];
        $quote->setSalesPerson($var); 
    }
}
public function saveQuoteAfter($evt){
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    if($quote->getSalesPerson()){
        $var = $quote->getSalesPerson();
        if(!empty($var)){
            $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_quote');
            $model->deteleByQuote($quote->getId(),'sales_person');
            $model->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
            $model->setKey('sales_person');
            $model->setValue($var);
            $model->save();
        }
    }
}
public function loadQuoteAfter($evt){
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_quote');
    $data = $model->getByQuote($quote->getId());
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $quote->setData($key,$value);
    }
}
public function saveOrderAfter($evt){
    $order = $evt->getOrder();
    $quote = $evt->getQuote();
    if($quote->getSalesPerson()){
        $var = $quote->getSalesPerson();
        if(!empty($var)){
            $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_order');
            $model->deleteByOrder($order->getId(),'sales_person');
            $model->setOrderId($order->getId());
            $model->setKey('sales_person');
            $model->setValue($var);
            $order->setSalesPerson($var);
            $model->save();
        }
    }
}
public function loadOrderAfter($evt){
    $order = $evt->getOrder();
    $model = Mage::getModel('custom/custom_order');
    $data = $model->getByOrder($order->getId());
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $order->setData($key,$value);
    }
}
```

}

Through Mage::log() I was able to see that the saveQuoteBefore() was only called on the billing step. That is why when I moved the field, it never recorded.

Is there another hook that I need to have it save on the review order step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in this post. Sorry to have wasted a question, but hopefully someone will be able to benefit.

[How to get Post Data from Magento's Onepage Checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461569/how-to-get-post-data-from-magentos-onepage-checkout)

Basically a js file is serializing the input fields. I had to slip it in with the agreements array of field names.